# Is asking where an obscure filesystem was used on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

While [chatting](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42611253#42611253) about data recovery, an [obscure filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type#PID_20h) has come up. It has a MBR partition ID (maybe?) — but while it appears in those ID tables there is never any indication of where it came from or where it is used. Some of them even suggest that this partition ID is only *rumoured* to exist.

Would asking about this filesystem's existence/use be within the scope of this site?

I do not have an actual example or evidence of its existence; it seems in the modern world this name only ever comes up when partition tables are corrupted.

Comment: I'd say it's perfect on topic, even more so it's a prime examples to be asked here. Well, of course it should be a bit dated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have other questions tagged [history](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) which ask about other obscure systems and devices.

I see no reason why you couldn't ask this.  There may be someone out there who remembers this filing system.  The page that you linked claims that it is supported by Windows Mobile.  If that is true, then I would say it is still on-topic for Retrocomputing as Windows Mobile is passing into history.

Comment: I think the Windows Mobile usage is a later redefinition of what that partition ID should be used for, but either way it'd still be on topic.

Comment: Thanks - I was worried it might be a bit too theoretical since I'm not even sure of its existence. But I guess that's what the answers are for. It definitely appeared (and likely disappeared?) before Windows Mobile; I've got more sources in the question proper.